# Looking for Ratings in a female dominated game by gender

Tags: data-request, sports, demographics, games

I have examined the male to female average rating difference in [chess](https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/chess-fide-ratings)
To determine if women are inherently worse at chess (on average) or if there is just a selective bias against them, I would now like to evaluate ratings in a similar female dominated game, but I am having trouble finding any (with available gendered ratings).
Could anybody point me to a usable dataset?

Comment: FYI: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12394/16193

Comment: @StanislavKralin I read that before posting, but it doesn't answer my question.